# Why are my ADODB queries not being persisted to the SQL server?

Tags: vb6, sql-server-2000, adodb

My VB6 program uses ADODB to do a lot of SQL (2000) CRUD.

Sometimes the network connection between the remote clients and the data center somehow "drops" resulting in the impossibility to establish new connections (so users launching the program can't use it).

The issue is the following: 
Anyone who is using the program at the moment of the "drop" can continue using it with no issues whatoever, perform every operation, update data, read data, and everything seems like is working normally.

User then proceeds to fire up a "sum-up" report which lists everything that was done (before or after the "drop").

If we then check the database, **all data regarding whatever was done after the network drop is not there**. User goes back into the program and everything is as it was before the network drop.

It seems like all queries where somehow performed in-memory ? I'm at a loss about how to even approach the issue (I'm familiar enough with VB6 to work with the source code but I don't know a lot about ADODB).

I haven't yet tried to replicate the behavior due to limited customer's availability (development environment is housed in their offices), I'll try starting up the program from the IDE then rip out the network cable.

Provided I can replicate the issue, how do I fix this ? Is there some setting I'm not aware of ?

On a side note: the issue is sporadic (it happened a handful of times during the last year, and the software is being used heavily and on a daily basis by mutiple concurrent users).

Comment: Feel free to ask for further information, I'm not sure about what might be useful to add to the question.

Comment: What are your connection settings?

Comment: are you using client-side or server-side cursors? This may help: [Using Disconnected Recordsets](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080101-1.shtml)

Comment: Using a client-server DBMS across a WAN is a dicey proposition at best.  Ignoring the hair-raising security risks of doing so, you probably consume a good deal of bandwidth and suffer from latency issues.  Data loss is a real threat if you aren't doing adequate error handling.  Move as much work as possible near the database into stored procedures or better yet middle-tier logic and thin down the clients.  Use a stateless web service to connect between your clients and middle-tier logic.

Comment: @Bob77 all good points, still, the software is in production now and is big, it just cannot be remade at the moment.

Comment: @deblocker After reading up about it, it looks like 'Disconnected Recordsets' is what's causing this (I didn't even know something like that existed). Still, I have no clue about how to eradicate this 'feature'.

Comment: @Alex: i'm sorry, but this isn't just only a "ugly VB6-ADO-M$ feature", this is really one of the common used strategies for database access over a WAN (Oracle, etc etc) , as Bob77 also pointed out. Before starting to code, you should familiarize with concepts like server-side-cursors, pessimistic-lock and so on, because ....

Comment: ... because i guess you need to take more a high-level decision as a quick & dirty patch to an older software. Maybe you will end up by increasing the frequency of the CRUD operations, or maybe you will try to handle deferred inconsistencies with a custom procedure, nobody other than you can take such a decision without a deep knowledge of what that software is doing and resources (bandwidth, & so on) you have available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up on Disconnected Recordsets, it seems that's what's behind this odd behavior I'm experiencing.

This is not something that can be simply "turned off".